# ProvisioningDeviceClient Create() fails in hosted App in Azure only

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-iot-hub

Running an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web App API in Azure.  Running the code locally works.  The code fails when hosted in Azure.  Nuget package is version 1.2.2 (Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client).

I removed the logging statements for readability:

```
using (var securityProvider = new SecurityProviderX509Certificate(pfxDeviceContents.certificate, pfxDeviceContents.collection))
                    {
                        using (var transport = new ProvisioningTransportHandlerHttp())
                        {
                            var globalendp = _configuration["ProvisioningEndpoint"];
                            var scope = _configuration["DpsScopeId"];

                            var provClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(globalendp, scope, securityProvider, transport);
....
```

The exception thrown is:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Access is denied
>      at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.Add(ICertificatePal certificate)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Add(X509Certificate2 certificate)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.CertificateInstaller.EnsureChainIsInstalled(X509Certificate2Collection certificates)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(String globalDeviceEndpoint, String idScope, SecurityProvider securityProvider, ProvisioningTransportHandler transport)

I've gone so far as taking the exact same certificate that fails in the hosted app and running it using a local instance of the same app.  So the certificate itself is not an issue.  Is there additional information i can gather to help solve this problem? Can anyone else confirm the use of this class in Azure is working?

Comment: Have you seen the questions with similar errors? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WindowsCryptographicException%3A+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is not supported.  The answer below might save someone time trying to figure out how to make this work

Microsoft's tech support answer follows:

**Symptom**

ProvisioningDeviceClient class does not work in Azure

**Cause**

The reason for the error is that the code is trying to write to the Intermediate CA.

https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client/1.2.2/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.dll/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client/CertificateInstaller?code=true#M%3AMicrosoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.CertificateInstaller.EnsureChainIsInstalled%28System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection%29

```
        _installedCertificates = new HashSet<string>();
        _lock = new object();
        try {
            using (X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)) {
                x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = x509Store.Certificates.GetEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                    X509Certificate2 current = enumerator.Current;
                    _installedCertificates.Add(current.Thumbprint);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (Logging.IsEnabled)
                Logging.Error(null, FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0} failed to read store: {1}.", "CertificateInstaller", ex), ".cctor");
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=netframework-4.7.2

CertificateAuthority
3
The X.509 certificate store for intermediate certificate authorities (CAs).

The sandbox generally aims to restrict access to shared components of Windows. Unfortunately, many core components of Windows have been designed as shared components: the registry, cryptography, and graphics subsystems, among others.

Please refer to the below document which has more detailed explanation.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions

**Resolution**

Another option is to use windows containers but currently this is in preview.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-windows-container-support-in-azure-app-service/

AppService can't open against the Intermediate Store to install a Certificate chain. The only way to install an Intermediate certificate chain is to upload a Certificate that contains the chain. If the webapp  run a VM then you have full control and can do what you want. If run a Cloud Service then things can be done in the Startup tasks. With App Service you have less control by design.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-compare

You are exactly correct on the DPS code requires a local cert store. As you mentioned , it has been added to the DPS SDK which was crafted as an alternative solution.